# CSS Last-Child Selector - affecting all my DIVs?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following

CSS

```
.streamBox {
 font-size:12px;
 background-color:#EDEFF4;
 border-bottom:1px solid #E5EAF1;
 margin-top:2px;
 padding:5px 5px 4px;
}
.streamBox:last-child {
   border: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="activityStream">

 <li class="story">
  <div class="streamBox nobkgcolor" id="">
  Stuff
  </div>
 </li>

 <li class="story">
  <div class="streamBox nobkgcolor" id="">
  Stuff
  </div>
 </li>

 <li class="story">
  <div class="streamBox nobkgcolor" id="">
  Stuff
  </div>
 </li>

</ul>
```

I thought the last-child selector would make it so the last DIV doesn't hav ea border... But instead all DIVs now don't have borders? y?

Suggestions on how w CSS to make it so JUST the last div doesn't have the border?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo but `<div class="box>blah blah</div>` You're missing a `"`. Also, which browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*For updated question:*

Your selector needs a tweak, it should be:

```
li:last-child .streamBox {
  border: none;
}
```

The `<div class="streamBox">` is both the first and last child of *its* parent, so your current selector matches all of them, instead you want the `<div>` inside the last `<li>`, so use the `:last-child` on the `<li>`, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/zbwuk/) (I changed the border to black to make it more obvious).

*For previous question:*
It's because you're missing a quote on the `class=""` attribute, fix it like this:

```
<div class="box">blah blah</div>
<div class="box">blah blah</div>
<div class="box">blah blah</div>
<div class="box">blah blah</div>​​​​
```

It'll then work as intended, the first 3 having borders, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Lm84g/).

Comment: @Fincha - It's the *only* problem, I commented on your answer as to why...you can see in the demo that it's the only problem.

Comment: Strange, it is working like that for me. Perhaps my example code didn't showcase the problem... Updated code edited above in my question... Also, this content is being injected into a DIV with jQuery ... not sure if that has an effect here. thx ideas?

Comment: @WozPoz - Your example's different, for that you need this selector: `li:last-child .streamBox`, it's the `<li>` that's a last-child, not the `<div>`, the `<div>` is both first and last child of it's `<li>`, so all of the `.streamBox` elements match that selector.

Comment: wow. I would never have figured that out. You're a genius . thank you!